# loadparm.c:4864, leaking memory?

Tags: 14.04, memory-leak

I’m running Ubuntu 14.04 Server with a LAMP stack, Samba, and FTP, no GUI, just SSHing into the server and working on it. I’m having trouble searching down a solution to this issue, but as far as I can Google for it, it *might* have something to do with Samba.

```
no talloc stackframe at ../source3/param/loadparm.c:4864, leaking memory??
```

The warning doesn't pop up at any kind of regular intervals or in response to the same or repeated actions. It pops up between things I’m doing - changing directories, editing files, copying stuff, and it often pops up when I first log in.

Has anyone got experience fixing this issue?

Comment: When do you see that message? Do you see it on a window or what?

Comment: i'm running Ubuntu 14.04 server edition... no GUI... just SSHing into the server and working on it.   It pops up between things i'm doing.   changing directories, editing files, copying stuff..  often pops up when i first log in

Comment: It is usually a good idea to search the internet for the error message. I did it, fount [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2214042) post and at the end there were 2 possible solutions.

Answer (score 39):

This problem is related to the samba `PAM` module.

There are 2 solutions.

### Solution 1:

Remove it with this command:

```
sudo apt-get remove libpam-smbpass
```

[Reference](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2214042)

### Solution 2:

Fix it by updating your `PAM` authentication module with this command:

```
sudo pam-auth-update
```

Remove the `SMB password synchronization` by using <kbd>Down Arrow</kbd> a few times and then <kbd>Space</kbd>. Then <kbd>Tab</kbd> to select <kbd>OK</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[Reference](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba/+bug/1257186)

Comment: And what if I want to use SMB password synchronization?

Comment: Then, Use of solution 2

Comment: What is solution #2? It is said "remove SMB password synchronization"?

Comment: No, just update the PAM Authentication module, Google it.

Comment: Both “solutions”, as you call them, actually disable password synchronization. Not a great idea, really.

Comment: How does this affect folder sharing if the Ubuntu installation is a virtual machine? Say Mac OS X running Virtualbox and Ubuntu 14.04 with shared folders.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like the folks at Samba have address the bug and have it staged for the next release:
https://bugzilla.samba.org/show_bug.cgi?id=8449

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running `fsck` on your partitions? That particular error for me seemed to have disappeared after running it.